# Is there a RadioHead library equivalent for STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32, radio, stm32cubeide

I have been using the RadioHead library for Arduino with devices such as RF95 and RF69, and have found it very useful for simplifying device interfacing (i.e. removing the need to implement all of the SPI function calls).

However, when using the STM32 MCUs, I am moving away from using the Arduino platform and preferring to use STM32CubeIDE. I am aware that you can run the Arduino framework on most STM32s (e.g. using VS Code and PlatformIO), but I have found that developing with the STM32CubeIDE can be faster and more effective.

Is there an equivalent to the RadioHead library for STM32CubeIDE, or is the only alternative to implement all of the SPI function calls yourself?

I'm aware that it is fairly trivial to just clone an Arduino library and translate it into STM32Cube function calls, but it feels like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It's not really rocket science to write simple stuff like SPI drivers by hand. That being said, the whole reason why the ST so-called "HAL" library exists is so that you can peek at it and copy relevant parts when writing a real driver. Available libs is a relatively new thing, it used to be that you had to write everything by hand with no reference examples at all. Which was admittedly a different kind of madness than bloatware libs, everyone was constantly re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Although... I think I have yet to find a single project involving SPI that didn't come with one exotic requirement or the other, which often meant tweaking the driver. And I might have used SPI... I dunno, in at least 30 different projects... So "I want to use a pre-made SPI lib" is already quite naive. SPI is perhaps the most poorly standardized thing out there.

Comment: Got me beat what you mean by ‘Arduino like cpus’ as Arduino is just an IDE and a semi - standard library. There’s no magic happening. It shouldn’t be difficult to translate the Arduino spi functions to cubemx. Personally I’d just borrow the Arduino core spi functions for the stm32 and tweak it to suit - the amount of code is trivial.

Comment: @Kartman By "Arduino-like MCU", I did mean anything that you would typically use the Arduino library to program; I have noticed that it is most typical to program ESPx and Atmel MCUs with Arduino framework. I have also noticed that many professionals will use STM32Cube to program the STM32. But yes, I get your point, I should have referred simply to the platform, Arduino, and not referenced MCUs.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I have noticed that most STM32 libraries available are actually clones of the Arduino implementation (e.g. a OneWire implementation for STM32Cube that I came across recently).

Comment: Manufacturer code builders like cubemx are handy for the more complex peripherals and for the initialisation code, but with peripherals like the uarts, spi and timers, they only address fairly vanilla use cases. Invariably you end up writing specific code that does direct register access which ends up faster and simpler.

Comment: True, I have found that when cloning an Arduino library, I do end up optimizing it for my specific case.

Comment: Nobody professional uses Arduino libs. I currently use "Atmel" (nowadays Microchip) MCUs but I have never gone near the Arduino mess. Instead there's the Atmel-provided bloat lib "ASF", which is about as badly written as ST's equivalent. These libs are only useful for reference at best.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, I have found that trying to use Arduino libs for professional stuff often causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: Might have found something, sharing here for posterity: https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib
(also: https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib/discussions/300)